# SUMIF Function Assistance

Tags: microsoft-excel

How would I go about adding the payments that do qualify with separating the ones that don't?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
=SUMIF(range,"criteria")
```

Replace `range` with cell range and `criteria` with a criteria like greater or smaller than x or comparing with another. An example to add values when they are greater than 10:

```
=SUMIF(range,">10")
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the data from A1 to C23.

[image]

If you want to get the sum of "Monthly Payment", where the corresponding cells of "Quality For Payments" is "Yes", please try the formula below.

```
=SUMIF(A2:A23,"=Yes",B2:B23)
```

If you want to get the sum of "Monthly Payment", where the corresponding cells of "Quality For Payments" is "No", please try the formula below.

```
=SUMIF(A2:A23,"No",B2:B23)
```